# I don't think my question would be valid for the main site, am I correct?

Tags: discussion, questions, quality-evaluation

I don't want my first post on a new StackExchange site to be a bad one. I was going to post the below question but I think it falls under the "Song Identification" category of the FAQ. If I am correct, does anyone have a recommendation on where I should go to ask my question?

---

Does the [little ditty](http://soundcloud.com/kberg/punch-line-1) that that is some times played after a joke have a real name?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, that would have been OT. Perhaps better for [Movies and TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/)? Although, I suppose you didn't know that when you asked the question. That kind of thing, we relegate to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/440/musical-practice-and-performance) around here.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't have to ask it, it is originally from the TV Variety show [Laugh In](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rowan_&_Martin%27s_Laugh-In#Catchphrases), it does not have a real name that I saw, but at least now I know where it is from.